# Best Approach to Learning ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-applications

I have been studying C# for quite sometime now and I would like to go into ASP.NET MVC Development.

However, I'm stuck on where to start and how I should approach the learning curve.

So what approach should I use to study deep into ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Read, Practice,Debug errors.  Repeat ....  Here is a getting started for newbies http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

Comment: Thank, I'm also going use the technique which Amit propose as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some good links:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207797/Learn-MVC-Model-View-Controller-step-by-step-in

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

From my experience, start with an idea for a site you would like to implement. Like store or social network site. Start with MVC hello world and slowly try to improve MVC capabilities client side as well.
You will have to learn HTML, CSS, JS (you can even try js client mvc such as angularJs).

Comment: Thank, I got an idea on how to approach it now